# How to flash phone, if it stucks in bootloop

Tags: cyanogenmod, bootloader

My phone gets stucked in a bootloop if I start it. The last thing I did was changing the fonts. I replaced droidsans by Segoe ui. Well I already deleted the cm10.zip on the phone and now can't flash it from CWM recovery. What shall i do now?

Comment: What kind of phone do you have?

Comment: LOL! Any phone!

Comment: The type of phone or device matters.

Answer (score -1):

I read that this procedure [here](http://droidmodderx.com/galaxynexus/unbrick-unroot-unlock-restore-your-galaxy-nexus-to-factory) helped others. You should give it a try.

Following the advice from ZnewmaN I am "copy-pasting" the instructions here. The article refers to Galaxy Nexus w/ Android 4.0.2 but you can follow similar steps for other scenarios too.

- Download the factory images to your PC.
- Unzip the file and its contents into your SDK/Tools folder (wherever your adb.exe and fastboot.exe files are). *Make sure they are not in their own folder, but have all been extracted to Tools.
- From within your Tools folder, open a command prompt (SHIFT + right click – “open command prompt here”):
- Type the following commands, allowing each to finish before moving onto the next:

`

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-toro-primekk15.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash radio radio-toro-i515.ek02.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot flash radio-cdma radio-cdma-toro-i515.ek05.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot -w update image-mysid-icl53f.zip
fastboot reboot-bootloader
fastboot oem lock
```

- Reboot your phone by highlighting “Start” and pressing the lock switch.
- It really is as simple as that. Your phone is now back to a 100% stock, unrooted and locked state.

Comment: Can you at least summarize what the link says? If that page were to ever go away this answer would be useless and not helpful to someone who might be trying to solve the same issue.

Comment: The guide is referring to specifically Nexus, other handsets may not have to do `fastboot flash radio` ... And furthermore - the OP did not indicate what handset either FWIW. :)